# Using PowerShell to Send a Mail Template with embedded Pic

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

Alright so this is tricky, or at least I think it is.

I want to send a list of recipients a welcome aboard email. Right now what I do is manually copy a mail in my Drafts folder in Outlook, appending the recipients and sending. Obviously that doesn't scale.

Sending mail with PowerShell is easy, sending HTML mail is easy; BUT I don't know how to send a mail that is based on this "template" which has two embedded PNGs (logos and such).

I wish I could something like:

```
$Body=OutLook.msg
```

Your thoughts?

PS
Right now I am experimenting with saving the Outlook message as HTML, this could be entirely the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Save a template message as an OFT file, then programmatically call `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate`. Populate the recipients appropriately (`MailItem.Recipients.Add`), modify the message body if you need to (`MailItem.HTMLBody`), and send it (`MailItem.Send`).

Comment: I'm reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx and http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_function_send_email.htm how and when do I call that namespace? Or are you suggesting that I use VBA? I'd like to automate this as much as possible and keep it out of Outlook altogether if need be.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "how and when do I call that namespace". Namespace object is returned from Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").

Comment: > Namespace object is returned from Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
In what language? PowerShell? Is there an assembly I have to load?

Comment: C:\..\scripts\ps>_ Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Application.GetNamespace : The term 'Application.GetNamespace' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.

Comment: Reading http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/12/17/hey-scripting-guy-december-17-2009.aspx now, hmmm

Comment: Outlook Object Model does not know or care which language it is being used from.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application

$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.Subject = "Top demand apps-SOURCE CLARIFICATION"
$mail.HTMLBody="<html><head></head><body><b>Joseph</b></body></Html>"
$mail.save()

$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Display()
```

Just replace the html content in the body session, it will open as a draft mail in outlook.